# BootstrapVue Modal opening outside of rendered nuxt element

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm using BootstrapVue with universal Nuxtjs.

The problem is; when I click the button, the b-modal element opened at the bottom of the body, not inside the rendered "_nuxt" div. For this reason, I can't set proper positions for the modal element. Maybe I want to open a modal element where I clicked the area.

But also, the bootstrap does not behave like that.

Let's prove it with a screenshot.

this is new boostrap-vue.org which developed with nuxtjs

[image: this is new boostrap-vue.org which developed with nuxtjs]

and this is getboostrap.org, modal rendered where clicked area

[image: and this is getboostrap.org, modal rendered where clicked area]

and lastly, If my memory is correct. normal Vue and BootstrapVue do not behave like that.

Thanks for patience :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap-Vue renders modals at the bottom of `body` by default.

If you want to render the modal where it's placed in the document, apply the `static` prop.

More information:
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal#lazy-loading-and-static-modals